# Are you able to offset a secondary y-axis in ChartJS, by a decimal value, whilst keeping the same scale for both y-axes?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am currently working with two datasets, both in meters, but the left hand axis displays a dataset with an offset of 11.74m along the y-axis. The right hand axis ignores this offset, hence y1 == y2 when y1 = 11.74 and y2 = 0.

This being the case, is there a way to keep integer tick values on both axes despite the decimal offset between the two? Not sure if I've got the Y2 offset correct in the graph below, but I think this is roughly what I'm trying to achieve - basically fixed gridline/tick intervals of Y1 for both axes, except for Y2:

[image]

The live code I'm working on is a bit too unwieldly for Stack Overflow, but the code below roughly achieves what I'm after - would be nice if there was a way to cleanly declare an offset of -0.26 without then also having to explicitly declare the rest of the ticks:

```
var ticks = [5, 4, 3, 2, 1, -0.26];
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
    datasets: [{
      data: [0, 0.1, 0.5, 5, 3.5, 3, 3.25, 2, 1.5, 1]
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkip: false,
          min: ticks[ticks.length - 1],
          max: ticks[0]
        },
        afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
          scale.ticks = ticks;
          return;
        },
        beforeUpdate: function(oScale) {
          return;
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wxp1fLk0/5/

Comment: If you want to maintain precision, this is not possible. If precision does not matter, just round the numbers.

Comment: Yes you can do it, you can look at this [example](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/samples/scales/stacked.html) for inspiration, you can use the [`stackWeight`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/linear.html#common-options-to-all-cartesian-axes) to define how much space the axis takes up

Comment: @LeeLenalee I don't think the stackWeight approach is what I'm after unfortunately - it doesn't seem to have any effect when I position a y2 axis on the right.

Comment: well without any code of you its pretty hard for people to help you

Comment: Apologies @LeeLenalee I've added some example code now - the website I'm working on obfuscates a lot of the ChartJS config, so wouldn't have been possible to copy/paste it into the description. Although I think the example code above will do the trick - I might just need to settle with some helper functions to automatically generate the tick array.

Answer (score 1):

Solution below after much fiddling. `offset` in the `getTickArray()` function specifies the left-hand axis value that coincides with `0` on the right hand axis. I think the `afterBuildTicks` and `beforeUpdate` keys then allow you to position ticks with more precision (I think).

https://jsfiddle.net/zjxukf57/47/

```
    function getRandomDataset(lowerBound, upperBound, count) {
        let output = [];
      
      for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
        let newPoint = Math.floor((Math.random() * upperBound) + lowerBound);
        output.push(newPoint);
        }
        
      return output;
    }
    
    function arrayMin(arr) {
      var len = arr.length, min = Infinity;
      while (len--) {
        if (arr[len] < min) {
          min = arr[len];
        }
      }
      return min;
    }
    
    function arrayMax(arr) {
      var len = arr.length, max = -Infinity;
      while (len--) {
        if (arr[len] > max) {
          max = arr[len];
        }
      }
      return max;
    }
    
    function getTickArray(offset, increment, leftData, rightData) {
        let ticksLeft = [];
      let ticksRight = [];
      
      let leftMin = arrayMin(leftData);
      let leftMax = arrayMax(leftData);
      let rightMin = arrayMin(rightData);
      let rightMax = arrayMax(rightData);
      
      let tick = leftMin;
      let tickRight = tick - offset;
      let wholeTick = Math.ceil(tick); // ? Gets first left-hand integer above minimum tick value
      let wholeTickRight = Math.ceil(tickRight); // ? Gets first right-hand integer above minimum tick value
      let maxValue = leftMax > rightMax + offset ? leftMax : rightMax + offset;
      
      // ? Push minimum decimal ticks
      ticksLeft.push(tick);
      ticksRight.push(tickRight);
      
      while (wholeTick < maxValue) {
        ticksLeft.push(wholeTick);
        ticksRight.push(wholeTickRight);
        
        wholeTick = wholeTick + 1*increment;
        wholeTickRight = wholeTickRight + 1*increment;
      }
      
      // ? Push minimum decimal ticks
      ticksLeft.push(maxValue);
      ticksRight.push(maxValue - offset);
      
        return [ ticksLeft, ticksRight ];
    }
    
    
    let datasetOne = getRandomDataset(8, 15, 10); // ? Ten random numbers between 8 and 15
    let datasetTwo = getRandomDataset(0, 7, 10); // ? Ten random numbers between 0 and 7
    
    var ticks = getTickArray(11.76, 2, datasetOne, datasetTwo);
    console.log(ticks)
    
    var ticks1 = ticks[0];
    var ticks2 = ticks[1];
    
    console.log(datasetOne);
    console.log(datasetTwo);
    
    // ? Chart Config
    var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
        datasets: [{
          data: datasetOne,
          yAxisID: 'A',
          label: "left",
          borderColor: "#FF0000",
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        },
        {
          data: datasetTwo,
          yAxisID: 'B',
          label: "right",
          borderColor: "#348632",
          backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)'
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            id: 'A',
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: false,
              min: ticks1[ticks1.length - 1],
              max: ticks1[0]
            },
            afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
              scale.ticks = ticks1;
              return;
            },
            beforeUpdate: function(oScale) {
              return;
            },
            gridLines: {
                       color: "#FF0000"
                    }
          },
          {
            id: 'B',
            ticks: {
              autoSkip: false,
              min: ticks2[ticks2.length - 1],
              max: ticks2[0],
              callback: function(value, index, values) {
                            return value;
                        }
            },
            afterBuildTicks: function(scale) {
              scale.ticks = ticks2;
              return;
            },
            beforeUpdate: function(oScale) {
              return;
            },
            position: "right",
            gridLines: {
                       color: "#348632"
                    }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
```